# escape character from column value in c#

Tags: c#

the following code read data from sqlserver2016 table and dump it in to a local folder. but some column value contains comma which displace value into another column as delimiter I have used comma, so how can I keep the comma in the value but not displace value into another column. my code sample as below. any help would be appreciated.

```
SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["db_connection"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);



            //Read data from table or view to data table
            string query = SQLQuery;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myADONETConnection);
            //myADONETConnection.Open();
            DataTable d_table = new DataTable();
            d_table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            myADONETConnection.Close();



            string FileFullPath = DestinationFolder + "\\" + FileNamePart + "_" + datetime + FileExtension;

            StreamWriter sw = null;
            sw = new StreamWriter(FileFullPath, false);

            // Write the Header Row to File
            int ColumnCount = d_table.Columns.Count;
            for (int ic = 0; ic < ColumnCount; ic++)
            {
                sw.Write(d_table.Columns[ic]);
                if (ic < ColumnCount - 1)
                {
                    sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                }
            }
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

            // Write All Rows to the File
            foreach (DataRow dr in d_table.Rows)
            {
                for (int ir = 0; ir < ColumnCount; ir++)
                {
                    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[ir]))
                    {
                        sw.Write(dr[ir].ToString());
                    }
                    if (ir < ColumnCount - 1)
                    {
                        sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                    }
                }
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

            }

            sw.Close();

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Comment: what do you mean with displace ? can you give the output you get and the one you want to get ?

Comment: value in database example, Column name: Data and Value:  "this is, sample" . But when I write it into csv file value fall into two separate column as "this is", and "sample", I would like entire value "this is, sample"  should be in one column in csv

Comment: Can't you use double quote if it  value have , in it ?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap all your values in quotes. This escapes the comma's and should be understood by whatever you use to parse the file later on.

The " is the default way of escaping in a csv.

The following should do the trick. This does assume your data does not contain any quotes.

```
sw.Write('"');
sw.Write(dr[ir].ToString());
sw.Write('"');
```

If your data does contain quotes you need to double those as shown below in order to escape them.

```
value1 | value2 | super"special"value 
"value1","value2","super""special""value"
```

Comment: if it contain any quote or other character how could I handle it